# Get the column data from excel using SQL

Tags: sql, excel

I have a main table with provides me employee details and this table references many lookup tables.

So the data is loaded into the DB by an excel sheet I get every week which contains the employee details. The lookup values also comes in the sheet as a column.

How can i check if the lookup value from excel already exists in SQL database?

Comment: Are you wanting Excel to perform SQL queries for you?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: So you want VBA Code that queries your DB and then checks if some of the Outputvalues are already in your Excel, correct?

Comment: Yes, this could help me. For example, there is a Designation column in the excel and a Designation lookup is there in DB. From the excel I should get the unique designations compare it with the lookup values and check any new value is present in excel. If new value is present, this value should be inserted into the dB.